# Unable to build an APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to build an APK in android studio.
I get this error:

```
:myApp:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\myApp\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar]
Preparing output jar [C:\MyApp\myApp\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
  Copying resources from program jar [C:\MyApp\myApp\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
        // react quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:'
    ...
    ..
    many different dependencies..
    ..
    }
```

It all started after I had problems with the project structure option - it wouldn't open.
So I deleted some folder in build-tools, and then the project wouldn't compile.
So I copied that folder from another computer back to that buils-tools folder again. It seemed as though everything worked fine both on phone and emulator. But now I've tried building an APK and that's what I'm getting.

Comment: Please post your build.gradle and manifest

Comment: did you try to clean the project ?

Comment: yes.. tried cleaning, rebuilding and what not

Comment: Does your manifest say its a multidex app or are you sub classing Application and initializing multidex? And do you even need Multidex?

Comment: I'm extending MultiDexApplication and then `protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
  super.attachBaseContext(base);
  MultiDex.install(this);
 }`

Comment: it all remained the way it was.. the problems started after what I wrote at the end of the post - with the build-tools folder

Answer (score 0):

I think the buildToolsVersion and target api should be the same level, not sure tough. try and change build tools version to: `23.0.2`

Comment: it says `failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.2`.. I am unable to install the build tools 23.0.2

Comment: Can you try 24.0.0?

Comment: And try and run build from terminal with stacktrace
Like this 
gradlew build --stacktrace

Comment: tried 24.0.0.. didn't help. Regarding the stacktrace , I'm not sure how to do it?
just go to the terminal and go to the sdk folder? then run `gradlew build --stacktrace`?

Comment: Ya, terminal in android studio. then just write gradlew build --stacktrace

Comment: it seems to be working now. After I updated to 24.0.0 it pointed me to some dependencies issues which I now resolved.
Thank you.
Edit your answer so that buildtoolsversion should be 24.0.0, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

update your sdk to latest build tools and change build version to version of latest build tool or you can download build tools 23.0.2 from sdk manager and install it.